# ASP.NET Core .NET Framework testing with cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc

I create a session middleware and want to test it. So I am using `TestServer` for testing purpose.

The test code looks as follow:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ComponentsTest.StartUps;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace ComponentsTest.IntegrationTest
{
  [TestFixture]
  public class SessionMwTest
  {
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
      _server = new TestServer(_hostBuilder);
    }

    private readonly IWebHostBuilder _hostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<StartUpSession>();
    private TestServer _server;

    [Test]
    public async Task BrowserRequestForCookies_SeveralRequest_ExpectToken()
    {
      var client = _server.CreateClient();
      var req1 = await client.GetAsync("/");

      var sid = (from r in req1.Headers
        where r.Key == "Set-Cookie"
        from h in r.Value
        where h.Contains("sid")
        select h).FirstOrDefault();
      StringAssert.Contains("sid", sid);

    }

  }
}
```

I want to make a request with the cookie, that I've got but do not know how to put the cookie to the request.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At its most basic, a Cookie is simply a header. You could store the sid value of `Set-Cookie` in a string and then for every request add the header:

```
request.Headers.Add("Cookie", new CookieHeaderValue(cookie.Name, cookie.Value).ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

httprequest container might be helpful https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer(v=vs.110).aspx

```
WebRequest _webReq = WebRequest.Create( uri );
HttpWebRequest _httpReq = _webReq as HttpWebRequest; 
_httpReq.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
```

Comment: The instance of TestServer contains a request and in that object i have to put cookie. The code that you show above, is not based on ASP.NET Core .NET Framework.